# How do I create linked nodes without user intervention?

Tags: 8

Suppose I have a cooking website where users can create `Recipe` nodes for `Food` nodes. For example, you might have a *Cake* node of type `Food`, and users should see an `Add Recipe` button on that page which takes them `node/add/recipe` except that the newly created `Recipe` node will have a reference to the parent *Cake* page.

I've added a `Content` type *Entity Reference* to to the `Recipe` node, which works fine. For programmatically generating the link I'm a bit lost though. I initially looked at using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) but it's still in alpha, and from the description it looks like I'd probably want to use the [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) module as well, but it doesn't have a version for 8.x at all.

Then I started looking at [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create/8.9.x), which is my current best guess for how to achieve the desired behaviour, but that still leaves me with some questions about what the best approach is;

1. How / Where do I capture the node reference when all I'm given is the EntityInterface type?
2. What is a mechanism for passing information about the reference/parent node to `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create` so that I can even know which reference to store?
3. How do I create links or buttons on the parent `Food` node that cause such information to be passed on to the hook?
4. Lastly, is this even the best approach, or am I missing a way that doesn't involve writing code?

I don't think I need any hand-holding or code, but I'd be very grateful for some pointers in the right direction for each of the above points from a veteran.

Comment: However you solve this, the main trick will be to use a custom route that includes the node ID for the Food item, eg. /node/{node}/add-recipe. That'll invoke a form controller to gather the fields you want for the recipe, so I'd start with the core node add form as a base.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong that's super helpful as I wouldn't have known about that option, thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, you'll have to create the route and the corresponding controller, but the solution can follow the approach I outlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that doesn't go deep into the code is to use the [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

It enables you to prepopulate form fields through the link to the form page:

> ```
> http://www.example.com/node/add/recipe?edit[field_entity_reference][widget][0][target_id]=123
> ```

You'll probably want to construct the links automatically, it can be done with Views. You create a Block Display that contructs the link using the Food information it's been placed on, through a contextual filter. When the Block is placed on Food pages the link leads to new recipe form that has the food where you just left from already filled in.

You can find more info about how to construct the link with the help of Views in this answer: [Add Prepopulate links to Node pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261199/pre-populate-an-entity-reference-when-adding-a-node-based-on-url-alias/262268#262268) part of the answer.